# How to securely limit access to Node fs in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, electron

I know it's recommended to use `fs` (filesystem module) only from the `main` process - but that's only half the battle, because if the code outside of `main` is determining what files are to be deleted, then the `main` process is still just receiving a path to a file to delete - which could be hijacked by a malicious action via something like `window.api.filesystem.deleteFile(somePath)`

So I considered to hardcode allowed/disallowed directories, but that's not particularly great either, because as soon as a user actually has a legitimate purpose to be reading/writing/deleting outside of the prescribed directory, you're right back in the same predicament of an attacker potentially being able to access their entire filesystem.

But the code can't all run in `main` without a thousand hour re-write of everything - nor does it seem advisable as blocking the `main` thread for even a moment freezes the app, its windows, its context menus, etc, for that moment.

The Electron security docs leave an enormous amount to be desired in this regard. What approaches are available to limit access by a potential attacker?

[There's a recommendation to "validate the sender of all IPC messages,"](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#17-validate-the-sender-of-all-ipc-messages) but that doesn't really seem to resolve the issue, because the privileged preload script APIs are available globally via `window.api...`, so an attacker could theoretically send a malicious command from a trusted window.

Otherwise, the [security docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) seem to entirely neglect this subject.

Comment: Can't you just treat this like a typical client/server design problem where the client can make requests till the cows come home, but the server decides what is and isn't safe to execute.  If you're saying that you have a thousand hour rewrite to fix your code into a proper design, then perhaps you need to get coding on that.  An untrusted client should never be dealing in absolute paths or have the freedom to specify any path it wants.  If that client just isn't trusted, then it should deal in named resources and the server decides what is and isn't safe in that regard.

Comment: "to fix your code into a proper design," -- but it's not even clear that it's proper, because of the blocking the main thread stuff...  Let's say a user wants to export a file to a given directory outside of our normal safe directories - how can we be certain that the request is from the user and that it isn't going to overwrite some important file with malicious contents? We can use the `wx` flag when writing the file to disallow overwriting, but that's the gist of my concern. Everything is hunky-dory, until we need to let a user choose their own path for something.

Comment: You either trust the user to specify their own directory location or you don't.   There is no in between.  If you don't, then you restrict what area of the file system they can access.  You can't possibly know their intentions and you can't possibly judge the effects of overwriting some arbitrary file in the file system.  If it is their own system they are messing with, then you can let the OS user privileges control what they can and cannot mess with and if they decide to shoot themselves in the foot, well that's their prerogative.

Comment: Look at a web browser.  It allows you to download a file and specify where you want it to go on your hard drive and what you want it to be named.   You are free to overwrite any file that you have file system privileges to write to.  If you want to do something dumb, you are allowed to.  You aren't required to protect a user from themselves more than that.

Comment: @jfriend00 the web browser model is what I'd love to emulate, only with the browser there's no way (besides exploits) that malicious code could open a file dialog and save a file, whereas with Electron those behaviors can be scripted as soon as someone has access to the preload script APIs, because Electron requires putting preload scripts in global scope. That's the very core of my issue. I don't need to only trust the user not to choose a dangerous directory, but also to not allow dangerous content in the application (which despite security measures, I cannot absolutely guarantee.)

Comment: I guess I'll probably limit reading and writing to the user's `Downloads` folder (in addition to our default directories,) because that's seemingly the best that can be done with the Electron security model.

Comment: Is this an end-user running an electron program on their own computer?  I'm missing the overall context that this security question fits into.

Comment: Yes it would be an end user running Electron on their own machine, but with user generated content. Although we sanitize the data and filter the requested paths, I'm still concerned by the fact that a malicious actor could programmatically achieve things not possible in a regular browser environment with Electron's security model. I'm probably overly concerned about this, but it's better than the alternative of not giving it a thought.

Comment: I'm not an electron expert by any stretch of the imagination, but, for displaying untrusted HTML content in your app, per [this page](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security), you can create an isolated webView that works like a regular browser page by disabling `nodeIntegration` and turning on `contextIsolation`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately we already use both of those options, but the Electron team insists only [`webPreferences.sandbox`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow) is really secure, because there could be exploits in `contextIsolation` iirc. Sandboxing is the rewrite alternative caused by Electron's security model completely changing, but then everything takes place in the `main` thread, so... It's a big pain and not something we can manage except piecemeal.